# C++ Arduino ESP8266 fucntion gives an exception, but running the same directly in loop works fine

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266

I wrote  function which should make a url request.

function:

```
int updateX(float x)
{
  if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    WiFiClient client;
    HTTPClient http;
    String sendStr = "192.168.1.1/updateXdeg?xDegVal="+String(x);
    http.begin(client, sendStr);
    int httpCode = http.GET();
    http.end();
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Wifi disconnected");
  }
}
```

when I execute the function in the main loop I get exception 0

```
--------------- CUT HERE FOR EXCEPTION DECODER ---------------

Exception (0):
epc1=0x40201145 epc2=0x00000000 epc3=0x00000000 excvaddr=0x00000000 depc=0x00000000

>>>stack>>>

ctx: cont
sp: 3ffffc70 end: 3fffffc0 offset: 0190
3ffffe00:  3fffdad0 00000000 41b1999a 40201138  
3ffffe10:  00000000 00000000 60831200 00000000  
3ffffe20:  3f010000 00001388 00000000 40212205  
3ffffe30:  00000000 00000000 00001a24 00000000  
3ffffe40:  00000000 00000430 00000000 00000000  
3ffffe50:  0011001f 00000000 00000000 4020fdb5  
3ffffe60:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
3ffffe70:  ffffffff 000e0000 00000000 3ffe000a  
3ffffe80:  00000000 00000020 00000000 00000000  
3ffffe90:  00000000 40207dec 00000000 00001388  
3ffffea0:  3fffdad0 00000000 00000000 00000000  
3ffffeb0:  00000000 00000000 0024002f 00000000  
3ffffec0:  00000000 0024002f 00000000 40201b60  
3ffffed0:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffee614 402011e7  
3ffffee0:  3fffff64 00000000 000b000f 00000000  
3ffffef0:  ff010050 fe001388 00000000 0015001f  
3fffff00:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
3fffff10:  00000000 0000001f 00000000 00000000  
3fffff20:  0011001f 00000000 00000000 40205db4  
3fffff30:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
3fffff40:  ffffffff 18b2b801 00000000 3ffe000a  
3fffff50:  00000000 3ffe8848 00000000 00000000  
3fffff60:  00000000 40207dec 00000000 00001388  
3fffff70:  000010e1 00000000 00000000 3ffef41c  
3fffff80:  00000000 00000000 002a002f 00000000  
3fffff90:  00000000 002a002f 00000000 402010a2  
3fffffa0:  feefeffe 00000000 3ffee614 40204bb8  
3fffffb0:  feefeffe feefeffe 3ffe85d8 40100b51  
<<<stack<<<

--------------- CUT HERE FOR EXCEPTION DECODER ---------------
```

this is the decoded stack result:

```
0x40201138: updateX(float) at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.2\cores\esp8266/WString.h line 79
0x40212205: tcp_enqueue_flags at core/tcp_out.c line 1085
0x4020fdb5: tcp_close_shutdown_fin at core/tcp.c line 448
0x40201b60: WiFiClient::~WiFiClient() at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src\WiFiClient.cpp line 101
0x40205db4: uart_write(uart_t*, char const*, size_t) at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.2\cores\esp8266\uart.cpp line 546
0x402010a2: setup() at C:\Users\User\OneDrive - sluz\Dokumente\Arduino\sketch_jan19b/sketch_jan19b.ino line 28
0x40204bb8: loop_wrapper() at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.2\cores\esp8266\core_esp8266_main.cpp line 201
```

When I run the same code from the updateX function directly in the main loop it works perfectly fine.

Comment: You declared your function to return an `int` but it does not `return` anything

Comment: @Odysseus omg, how could I miss that. I'm sorry for that and thanks for your help.

Comment: You should enable compiler warnings and respect them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My function was declared to return an integer, but I didn't return anything.